# How do I cache DNS lookups for Laravel database connections?

Tags: php, laravel, dns

I would like to know how I can cache DNS lookups of CNAMEs used for database connections, such as MySQL and Redis. How can this be done with Laravel?

Comment: I recommend against using public DNS resolvers, especially for internal stuff. Instead just install a local caching resolver, like `unbound` on the host, that will help all applications there. The default `unbound` config works, as long as the box has correct connectivity and DNS ports open. Otherwise or in more elaborate setups you can also configure it to forward to some internal DNS resolver.

Comment: @Machavity harding IP addresses is really not a good idea...

Comment: @Machavity the problem is caching DNS resolutions, not getting rid of DNS altogether. So the solution is implementing a caching resolver somewhere, not getting rid of all names and hardcoding IP addresses.

Comment: @Machavity I still disagree. Even if they are static **today** it is not a good idea to hardcode them in the application. Because everything supposed not to change will change in the future, and it is bad to create problems. At least, you could add entries in `/etc/hosts` so that you bypass true DNS resolutions and you kind of hardcode the IP addresses, which is still bad but at least independant from your application and only a system/network issue that can evolve independently from the application's  code.

Comment: @Machavity Hardcoding IP addresses in application is wrong, doing it in `/etc/hosts` can be a temporary workaround but kind of always create troubles in the future (especially if not documented), so what only remains is fixing the DNS problems to keep using names everywhere and not IP addresses. I am just replying to your comment being *you could hard-code them* and I disagree for the reasons given, that is all.